# Track changes using interactive markdown editor

Tags: markdown, pagedown

Is there a way to get the interactive markdown editor to do basically what a word processors "track changes" does.

For example, the editor is pre-loaded with the following text.

`The small brown dog jumped over the lazy fox`

Then the user changes the text to the following:

`The small brown dog jumped under the lazy fox`

I want the following to be displayed:

> The small brown dog jumped <strike>over</strike>*under* the lazy fox

Does pagedown (or any other interactive web-based markdown editor) have such a feature?

Comment: So diff between versions?

Comment: Better discussion on this topic across here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945728/ms-word-track-changes-and-rmarkdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not fully integrated into your editor, but you can get this effect with some of the javascript diff implementations. jsdiff, for example, does what you're describing: http://kpdecker.github.io/jsdiff/ . Xindiff also does this.

Comment: Link is rotten.

Comment: Now http://kpdecker.github.io/jsdiff/