# tracking changes in journal aricles prepared using rmarkdown to communicate with non R users

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, tracking

As a fairly new R user, I find that `r-markdown` is amazingly efficient for writing research articles with many numbers, graphs and tables. My question is: when different collaborators (non R users) have made some changes in the knitted Word manuscript file, what is the best way to track those changes in the `r-markdown` file, and the final Word file?

I noticed some similar questions were asked and answered a few years ago, including: [MS Word track changes and RMarkDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945728/ms-word-track-changes-and-rmarkdown).
With new features and new packages such as `reviewer` and `trackmd` recently becoming available, I wonder if anyone could suggest an updated workable workflow for this. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but the demos look good: https://github.com/noamross/redoc